# How to create dynamic tab content in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, tabs

I am trying to create a dynamic tab, in which it will have some form (input text box, grid etc).
So far i am successful in  creating dynamic tab. But i am stuck on making individual input form for each tab. For eg. I need the Description Text box model to be unique for each tab. And RequestsGridOptions should display corresponding data for each tab.

Here is my code

```
 <tabset type="pills">
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in selectedIPPLots track by $index" heading="{{tab.Descritpion}}" 
       active="tab.active" 
       disable="tab.disable">
    <div  class="container" style="margin:5px;border: 1px solid #ddd;margin-left:1px;width:1000px">

                    <div class="input-w" ng-repeat="lotD in LotDescriptionModel">
                      <label for="lotD" style="margin:20px;">Description</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lotD" Style="width:200px;margin:10px;" ng-model="lotD" />

                    </div>
                    <kendo-grid options="RequestsGridOptions" style="margin:5px">
                    </kendo-grid>
                    <label for="fileUpload" style="margin:10px;">Attach Terms of Reference for the Lot</label>
                    <input id="fileUpload" type="file" name="attachment" class="form-control"  style="width:300px" />
                    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin:5px">Save</button>
                  </div>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

Is there a way to do this?
thanks